# jQuery search and filter table

Tags: jquery, search, filter

I was looking for a jQuery plugin that'll filter a table according to input values.

I came across http://rikrikrik.com/jquery/quicksearch/, but I can't figure out how to make it work for an already existing input box.

Currently it creates a new input form for me (which I don't want) but I'd like to be able to use it with an existing input box that has a input submit button.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like time has answered your question for you. [QuickSearch](http://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch) does in fact allow you to attach the search function to a preexisting text input box.

riklomas mentions that:

> Note that the usage has changed in the latest version of quicksearch, the code is not backwards compatible, the form and input are not build by the script any more.

I've just started using it today and it looks like it works pretty well. It does appear to eat up it's share of CPU, at least on my testing environment (Firefox 3.6, OS X, and a pretty large data set), but that's probably not unique to this particular plugin.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with this plug-in out-of-the-box, unless you dig into its code and modify it to do this.

The search inputbox is automatically generated by its own javascript and there are no options to change that behavior.

Comment: This was probably true back when @ichiban wrote it, but it's not any more; see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Adam, try firing the onKeyUp of the plugin-generated text field.
First, you need to know the id of that field (use firebug), let's say it's `generated_fld`, then the code will be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#my_other_input").keyup(function(){
       $("#generated_fld").val($(this).val()).keyup();
   })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this code for a while. First:

1. The input text field to filter/search has id 'search'
2. Actually it just use the first cell of each row, you can easily extend this (follow the comments on the code)

The Code:

```
$('#search').on('input', function () {
    var str = $('#search').val().toLowerCase();
    $("#containerTable tr").each(function (index, element) {
        var label = $(this).find("td").eq(0).html().toLowerCase();
        //var labelx = $(this).find("td").eq(x).html().toLowerCase();
        //...

        if (str == '' || label.indexOf(str) != -1) {
           // || labelx.indexOf(str) != -1) ...
           $(this).css("display", "table-row");
        }
        else {
           $(this).css("display", "none");
        }
    });        
});
```